# WPF ListBox Elastic Scroll on Touch Devices

Tags: wpf, listbox

I have a wpf ListBox defined in xaml as follows

```
<ListBox HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}">

        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>

        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <DockPanel Width="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListBox}}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayText}"></TextBlock>
                </DockPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

</ListBox>
```

This gives a horizontal scrolling list box where each item consumes the entire width of the list box. When using this on a touch device, dragging your finger across the list box moves through the items in a continuous manner, i.e., I can drag my finger and have the last half of the first item showing and the first half of the second item showing.

What I'd like is for the item to elastically default to whichever item is taking up the majority of the viewport. For example, if I drag my finger such that one-third of the first item is showing, and two-thirds of the second item is showing, and release my finger, the list box will "elastically" scroll to the second item. Is there a way to do this with ListBox?